# Mining UBIQ and DBIX using open-ethereum-pool

Tags: go-ethereum, mining-pools, hash-algorithm

Open-Ethereum-Pool is configured to mine Ethereum; how do I configure it to mine UBIQ (which uses ethash) and DBIX coins?

Thanks for answers